# php regex match exact number 10 in an URL

Tags: php, regex

I have an URI like

```
myurl-c-10_550_05.html
```

I would like to match any URI containing the exact number 10 anywhere , like :

```
myurl-c-10_550_05.html
myurl-c-550_10_05.html
myurl-c-550_05_10.html
myurl-c-550_10.html
myurl-c-10.html
```

but not 100 or 1000 like

```
myurl-c-100_550_05.html  << Wrong
```

What I tried and working for the figure 10 or 100 or 1000  is :

```
preg_match("/-c-(?:[0-9_]+|)(10)(?:[0-9_]+|)/",$baseuri)
```

But I can't get the fixed 10 figure even whith this other regex :

```
preg_match("/-c-(?:[0-9_]+|)(^10$)(?:[0-9_]+|)/",$baseuri)
```

I've spent nearly 2 hours on stackoverflow , reading a lot, trying a lot with this cool tool :

https://regexr.com/4eis5

EDITED : 
this regex should also check there is a -c- in the uri followed by some digits and undersocre or not and ending with a point.

```
not working : myurl-i-10_gasp.html
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks !

Sebastien

Comment: `(?<!\d)10(?!\d)`

Comment: https://regexr.com/4eish

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I omit to precise this regex should only work with -c- page  or to be more precise to work with -c-xxxxxx.html the regex only applies  in the xxxx.

Comment: I modified some  regex to Toto and it is fine ! https://regexr.com/4eit3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
"/-c-(\d+_)*10\D/"
"/-c-(\d+_)*10(?!\d)/"
```

Comment: Thanks but not fully compliant

Comment: Steffen, try your regex on this sample : https://regexr.com/4eit3
you'll see it missed some url with 10

Comment: @SebastienR. All regexes match the first 5 lines.

Comment: Steffen, my bad ! I probably missed my copy/paste last time. Nice thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the help of Toto :

```
-c-(?:[0-9_]+|)(?<!\d)10(?!\d)
```

You can see it working here: https://regexr.com/4eit3